# Get number of days for the last two dates for every cells with same ID in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have data like shown below.

```
ID          Date
8215    3/11/2013
8215    3/11/2011
8215    3/12/2009
8215    3/10/2007
18150   3/1/2013
18150   3/4/2011
18150   3/4/2009
18150   3/1/2008
18150   3/6/2006
```

Desired Results:

```
ID          Num_days
8215        731  
18150       641
```

I would like to get the number of days for the last two dates for entity with ID 8215. In this example the number of days would 731 and 641 for ID 18150. It's hard to get the number of dates for the last two dates when I have over 70k entities. How can I do this so I can calculate the average later on?

Comment: your data is already sorted? and you want to get the difference of the latest 2 dates for each entity?

Comment: @L42 - Yes. All sorted. Just want the number of days from last two dates.

Comment: why 641? shouldn't it be 728 for 18150?

Comment: Andy's answer should work.

Comment: @pnuts American i assume? OP didn't elaborate it as well. :)

Comment: It's UK. See my screencap for my answer. It matches OP's values. :)

Comment: @pnuts hehe well, i agree with BK201, Andy already got it :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I can't accept all the answers given here. A great thank you to BK401 for the screencaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with a list of unique IDs in column D, this should work. No sorting required:

```
=LARGE(IF($D2=$A:$A,$B:$B),1)-LARGE(IF($D2=$A:$A,$B:$B),2)
```

Confirm with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

It will be faster if you limit the ranges `$A:$A` and `$B:$B`.

Edit: I interpreted "last two dates" to mean "most recent two dates". Another interpretation might be "most recent two entries in an ordered descending list". In the latter interpretation use this instead:

```
=SMALL(IF($D2=$A:$A,$B:$B),2)-SMALL(IF($D2=$A:$A,$B:$B),1)
```

Comment: +1: I think she meant two latest, but props for going the extra mile. It might ***indeed*** mean the last two dates in a list, or two smallest. Ambiguous, really. :)

Comment: @pnuts: Yep, which confirms two things: that she's using UK time, and that she wanted the most recent two dates. If you check my edit history, I even thought she referred to the end dates. After reading Andy's answer, I thought it's done. But then, *latest* could mean the bottom two per ID as sorted, which is the two smallest, basically. It's really ambiguous. As OP has accepted answer, I think it's pretty clear that it's the two *most recent* she wants. Should we edit her post? :/

Comment: Tested: ID 8215 gives the same result (731) using the "most recent dates" (LARGE) formula, given mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format. However, result 641 for ID 18150 only comes about using LARGE and dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your requirement, but would something like:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,B2-B3,"")
```

copied down to suit serve?

Comment: I edited my post to add desired results. I only need the num of days for last two dates for the same ID. If I copy down your method, I would have the number of days of all the dates listed for same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is in column A, and dates are in column B, you would create column C, such that row 2 would read:

```
=(A2=A1) * (A2<>A3) * (B2-B1)
```

The first part (A2=A1) returns 1 if the ID is the same as the previous row, or 0 otherwise.  The next part returns 1 if the ID is not the the same as the next row (so so far you have 1 if you're in the last row of the ID, 0 otherwise), and the last part (B2-B1) gets the number of days between the two dates.  This will return 0 or the number of days

Answer (score 0):

This works even without sorting. It's an array formula that gets the two largest dates based on condition and calculates the difference.

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=8215,B:B))-LARGE(IF(A:A=8215,B:B),2)
```

This is an **array** formula so use <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd> when inputting it.

It's better if you have a unique list somewhere, change `8215` to refer to the range, and just drag down.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Hope this helps.